# Flutter ListView is not updating when the list items are changed

Tags: sqlite, flutter, dart, sqflite

I started learning Flutter. I am developing a simple application using it. Now, I am developing a feature where my application will display the records from the SQLite database and where the user adds the new records into the SQLite database. But my ListView is displaying the blank screen.

I have a class called DatabaseHelper with the following code.

```
class DatabaseHelper {
  static DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper;
  Database _database;

  String noteTable = 'note_table';
  String colId = 'id';
  String colTitle = 'title';
  String colDescription = 'description';
  String colPriority = 'priority';
  String colDate = 'date';

  DatabaseHelper._createInstance();

  factory DatabaseHelper() {
    if (_databaseHelper == null) {
      _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper._createInstance();
    }

    return _databaseHelper;
  }

  Future<Database> get database async {
    if (_database == null) {
      _database = await initializeDatabase();
    }

    return _database;
  }

  Future<Database> initializeDatabase() async {
    Directory directory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = directory.path + 'notes.db';
    var notesDatabase = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _createDB);

    return notesDatabase;
  }

  void _createDB(Database db, int newVersion) async {
    await db.execute('CREATE TABLE $noteTable($colId INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, $colTitle TEXT, $colDescription TEXT, $colPriority INTEGER, $colDate TEXT)');
  }

  Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> getNoteMapList() async {
    Database db = await this.database;

    return await db.query(noteTable, orderBy: '$colPriority ASC');
  }

  Future<int> insertNote(Note note) async {
    Database db = await this.database;

    return await db.insert(noteTable, note.toMap());
  }

  Future<int> updateNote(Note note) async {
    var db = await this.database;

    return await db.update(noteTable, note.toMap(), where: '$colId = ?', whereArgs: [note.id]);
  }

  Future<int> deleteNote(int id) async {
    var db = await this.database;

    return await db.rawDelete('DELETE FROM $noteTable WHERE $colId = $id');
  }

  Future<int> getCount() async {
    Database db = await this.database;
    List<Map<String, dynamic>> x = await db.rawQuery('SELECT COUNT(*) FROM $noteTable');

    return Sqflite.firstIntValue(x);
  }
}
```

Then I have a widget called NoteList with the following code where the list of items are displayed.

```
    class NoteList extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return _NoteListState();
      }
    }

    class _NoteListState extends State<NoteList> {
      List<Note> _notes = [];
      int _count = 0;
      DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();

      _NoteListState() {
        this._notes = getNotes();
        this._count = _notes.length;
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(title: Text("Notes"),),
          body: Container(
            child: getListView(context),
          ),
          floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
            child: Icon(Icons.add),
            onPressed: () {
              navigateToNoteForm("Add Note");
            },
          ),
        );
      }

      Widget getListView(BuildContext context) {
        return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: _count,
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return ListTile(
                leading: CircleAvatar(
                  backgroundColor: _notes[index].priority == 1? Colors.yellow: Colors.red,
                  child: Icon(_notes[index].priority == 1 ? Icons.arrow_right : Icons.add),
                ),
                title: Text(_notes[index].title),
                subtitle: Text(_notes[index].date),
                trailing: Icon(Icons.delete),
                onTap: () {
                  navigateToNoteForm("Edit Note", _notes[index]);
                },
              );
            });
      }

      void navigateToNoteForm(String pageTitle, [Note note]) async {
        bool result = await Navigator.push(context, MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
          return NoteForm(pageTitle, note);
        }));

        if (result) {
          setState(() {
            debugPrint("Updating list");
            _notes = getNotes();
            _count = _notes.length;
          });
        }
      }

      List<Note> getNotes() {
        List<Note> notes = List<Note>();
        Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> notesFuture = _databaseHelper.getNoteMapList();
        notesFuture.then((notesMap) {
          debugPrint("Total notes found in the database ${notesMap.length}");
          notesMap.forEach((map) {
            notes.add(Note.fromMapObject(map));
          });
        });

        return notes;
      }
    }


Then I also have another widget class called NoteForm with the following code.


class NoteForm extends StatefulWidget {
  String _title = "";
  Note _note = null;

  NoteForm(String title, [Note note]) {
    this._title = title;
    this._note = note;
  }

  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return _NoteFormState();
  }
}

class _NoteFormState extends State<NoteForm> {

  double _minimumPadding = 15.0;
  var _priorities = [ 1, 2 ];
  var _titleController = TextEditingController();
  var _descriptionController = TextEditingController();
  var _dateController = TextEditingController();
  DatabaseHelper _databaseHelper = DatabaseHelper();
  var _selectedPriority = 1;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text(widget._title),),
      body: Builder(
        builder: (scaffoldContext) => Form(
          child: Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(_minimumPadding),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _titleController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Title",
                        hintText: "Enter title"
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: EdgeInsets.all(_minimumPadding),
                    child: TextFormField(
                      controller: _descriptionController,
                      decoration: InputDecoration(
                          labelText: "Description",
                          hintText: "Enter description"
                      ),
                    ),
                  )
              ),
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(_minimumPadding),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _dateController,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        labelText: "Date",
                        hintText: "Enter date"
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(_minimumPadding),
                  child: DropdownButton<int>(
                    value: _selectedPriority,
                    items: _priorities.map((dropdownItem) {
                      return DropdownMenuItem<int>(
                        value: dropdownItem,
                        child: Text(dropdownItem == 1? "Low": "High"),
                      );
                    }).toList(),
                    onChanged: (int newSelectedValue) {
                      setState(() {
                        _selectedPriority = newSelectedValue;
                      });
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                child: Padding(
                  padding: EdgeInsets.all(_minimumPadding),
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    child: Text(
                        "Save"
                    ),
                    onPressed: () {
                      _save(scaffoldContext);
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      )
    );
  }

  void _save(BuildContext context) async {
    Note note = Note();
    note.title = _titleController.text;
    note.description = _descriptionController.text;
    note.date = _dateController.text;
    note.priority = _selectedPriority;

    if (widget._note != null && widget._note.id!=null) {
      //update
      _databaseHelper.updateNote(note);
      this.showSnackBar(context, "Note has been updated.");
    } else {
      //create
      _databaseHelper.insertNote(note);
      this.showSnackBar(context, "Note has been added.");
    }

    closeForm(context);
  }

  void showSnackBar(BuildContext context, String message) {
    var snackBar = SnackBar(
      content: Text(message),
      action: SnackBarAction(
        label: "UNDO",
        onPressed: () {

        },
      ),
    );

    Scaffold.of(context).showSnackBar(snackBar);
  }

  void closeForm(BuildContext context) {
    Navigator.pop(context, true);
  }
}
```

When I run my application, it is just displaying the blank screen as follows.

[image]

As you can see I am logging out the number of records returned from the database using debugPrint method. It is saying that there are 6 records within the database. It is just not displaying the records. What is wrong with my code and how can I fix it?

Comment: make getNotes async method and use  getNotes().then((noteresponce){ setState((){ _notes=noteresponce; _count = _notes.length;}  }); i think setState is calling before it gets data from database.

Comment: Hi, this helps. Thanks a lot. I changed my getNotes method to something like this. Do you want to post answer? I can accept it.
void getNotes() {
    List<Note> notes = List<Note>();
    Future<List<Map<String, dynamic>>> notesFuture = _databaseHelper.getNoteMapList();
    notesFuture.then((notesMap) {
      debugPrint("Total notes found in the database ${notesMap.length}");
      notesMap.forEach((map) {
        notes.add(Note.fromMapObject(map));
      });

      setState(() {
        _notes = notes;
        _count = notes.length;
      });
    });
  }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As i mention in comment that was happening because of async task take some time to perform and if you do not keep it async then setState function execute before actual data load or set.

So Following changes solve your issue.

make `getNotes async method` And

```
getNotes().then((noteresponce){ setState((){ _notes=noteresponce; _count = _notes.length;} });
```